# GridSplitter in a Frame; expand beyond border problems

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, gridsplitter

I've got a generic view for displaying data in a Silverlight RIA application. Basically, the view takes in a parameter which is the query required by RIA to get the data, and the data is displayed using autogenerated fields.

Here's part of the XAML code for the view.

```
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="DataGridRow"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="DataFormRow"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="EditRow"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ria:DomainDataSource Name="SQLDomainDataContext" LoadingData="SQLDomainDataContext_LoadingData" LoadSize="45" SubmittedChanges="SQLDomainDataContext_SubmittedChanges" SubmittingChanges="SQLDomainDataContext_SubmittingChanges" LoadedData="SQLDomainDataContext_LoadedData">
                <ria:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
                    <ria:SortDescriptor Direction="Descending" PropertyPath="BaseProperties.CreatedOn" />
                </ria:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
            </ria:DomainDataSource>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <sdk:DataGrid  Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged" />
                <custCont:LocalizedDataPager Grid.Row="1" x:Name="pager" Source="{Binding Path=Data}" PageSize="15" DisplayMode="FirstLastPreviousNext" />
            </Grid>

            <Border Grid.Row="1">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF9D9D9D" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDBDBDB" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Ellipse Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="4" Height="4" Margin="8,0"/>
                    <Ellipse Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="4" Height="4" Margin="8,0"/>
                    <Ellipse Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="4" Height="4" Margin="8,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <sdk:GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" Opacity="0"/>

            <data:DataForm Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="DF" AutoCommit="False" 
                           DataContext="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                           AutoGeneratingField="DF_AutoGeneratingField" EditEnded="DF_EditEnded" DeletingItem="DF_DeletingItem" Style="{StaticResource DataFormStyle}"/>

            <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Column="0" Name="btnHideDF" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ApplicationResources}, Path=ApplicationStrings.ShowEntities_HideDfBtn}" MinWidth="10" Margin="2" Click="btnHideDF_Click" />
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Name="bRefresh" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ApplicationResources}, Path=ApplicationStrings.ShowEntities_RefreshBtn}" MinWidth="75" Margin="2" Click="bRefresh_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanLoad}" />
                <Button Grid.Column="3" Name="btnCacnelChanges" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ApplicationResources}, Path=ApplicationStrings.ShowEntities_CancelChangesBtn}" Margin="2" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=HasChanges}" Click="btnCacnelChanges_Click" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <Button Grid.Column="4" Name="bSubmit" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ApplicationResources}, Path=ApplicationStrings.ShowEntities_SubmitBtn}" MinWidth="75" Margin="2" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=HasChanges}" Click="bSubmit_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

When the view is displayed in a singular `Frame`, all is well. But when it is displayed on a page with TWO frames, odd things begin to happen. If the user grabs the splitter and moves it all the way to the top, beyond the frames boundaries, the `DataForm` will expand endlessly. This isn't a big issue, but it looks ugly, and makes the buttons at the bottom vanish from sight.

What's going on here? Why is this happening? How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my Google-fu was weak.

I found [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/215176/510326.aspx) today, and it describes the exact same problem I had, as well as a possible solution.

Still, I didn't expect this to be a bug in SL...